# Android Studio Missing Keystore on SigninReport

Tags: android, android-studio, keystore, android-keystore

i was trying to run signinReport to see my Sha1 when it gave me this error:

[image]

But I wanted to say that a few days ago I moved the project from one PC to another but with it I also moved the jks signature. will it be an error created by the old keystore signature path? how can i solve?